# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read' when posting image to database

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to troubleshoot my python database by posting an image to it. However whenever I send the post request I receive the following error.

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
line 98, in add_file
    new_file = File(name, file_type, data.read())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Here's the code I have as of now.

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, send_file
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_heroku import Heroku
import io

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "postgres://wbzxqshctunral:df393ee4891d46d62fdfa0daf99f0cd5ba4563268340386d5caf85904f470c71@ec2-34-224-229-81.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/drj57s4cb9qkq"

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)

heroku = Heroku(app)
CORS(app)



class VehicleInformation(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    make = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    model = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    mpgE = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    year = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    
    
    def __init__(self, make, model, mpgE, year, description):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.mpgE = mpgE
        self.year = year
        self.description = description

class VehicleInformationSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ("id", "make", "model", "mpgE", "year", "description")

vehicle_information_schema = VehicleInformationSchema()
multiple_vehicle_information_schema = VehicleInformationSchema(many=True)

class File(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    file_type = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    data = db.Column(db.LargeBinary, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, name, file_type, data):
        self.name = name
        self.file_type = file_type
        self.data = data

class FileSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ("id", "name", "file_type")

file_schema = FileSchema()
files_schema = FileSchema(many=True)


@app.route("/vehicle/add", methods=["POST"])
def add_vehicle():
    if request.content_type != "application/json":
        return jsonify("Error: Data must be sent as JSON")
    vehicle_data = request.get_json()
    make = vehicle_data.get("make")
    model = vehicle_data.get("model")
    mpgE = vehicle_data.get("mpgE")
    year = vehicle_data.get("year")
    description = vehicle_data.get("description")
    
    record = VehicleInformation(make, model, mpgE, year, description)
    
    db.session.add(record)
    db.session.commit()
    
    return jsonify("Vehicle has been added successfully")

@app.route("/vehicle/all_vehicles", methods=["GET"])
def get_all_vehicles():
    all_vehicles = db.session.query(VehicleInformation).all()
    return jsonify(multiple_vehicle_information_schema.dump(all_vehicles))

@app.route("/vehicle/delete", methods=["DELETE"])
def delete_vehicle(id):
    vehicle_data = db.session.query(VehicleInformation).filter(VehicleInformation.id == id).first()
    db.session.delete(vehicle_data)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify("Vehicle has been eradicated")

@app.route("/file/add", methods=["POST"])
def add_file():
    name = request.form.get("name")
    file_type = request.form.get("type")
    data = request.files.get("data")

    new_file = File(name, file_type, data.read())
    db.session.add(new_file)
    db.session.commit()

    return jsonify("File added successfully")

@app.route("/file/get/data", methods=["GET"])
def get_file_data():
    file_data = db.session.query(File).all()
    return jsonify(files_schema.dump(file_data))

@app.route("/file/get/<id>", methods=["GET"])
def get_file(id):
    file_data = db.session.query(File).filter(File.id == id).first()
    return send_file(io.BytesIO(file_data.data), 
                    attachment_filename=file_data.name, 
                    mimetype=file_data.file_type)

@app.route("/file/delete/<id>", methods=["DELETE"])
def delete_file(id):
    file_data = db.session.query(File).filter(File.id == id).first()
    db.session.delete(file_data)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify("File Deleted Successfully")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I appreciate the help in advance!

Comment: Show us the html template that has the form.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you aren't handling error cases where, for example, `data` isn't passed to the request:

```py
@app.route("/file/add", methods=["POST"])
def add_file():
    name = request.form.get("name")
    file_type = request.form.get("type")
    data = request.files.get("data")
    
    if data is None:
        return jsonify("Missing file!")

    # You should probably have the same checkers for name and file_type

    new_file = File(name, file_type, data.read())
    db.session.add(new_file)
    db.session.commit()

    return jsonify("File added successfully")
```